# joint probability basics

Tags: probability

I was going through articles on joint probability

one article says

> if $A$ and $B$ are two independent event then joint probability of $A$ and $B$, $P(A,B)  = P(A) \cdot P(B)$

Other articles go one step further to explain via a joint probability table, like for example below

Below picture is from below link :- [Bayes Network](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/cogs501/Bayes1.html)

[image: joint probability]

If we were to combine both the definitions then they are not matching up. For example

$P(female, math) = P(female) \cdot P(math) = 0.24 \cdot 0.506 = 0.12144$ but what is given is $0.13$.

Comment: Read the section below Table 4 where it explains that, for one, $$\mathsf P(\textrm{female}, \textrm{math})~{=~\mathsf P(\textrm{female}\mid \textrm{math})~\mathsf P(\textrm{math})\\=~\mathsf P(\textrm{female})~\mathsf P(\textrm{math}\mid\textrm{female})}$$Which would only equal $\mathsf P(\textrm{female})\mathsf P(\textrm{math})$ **if the events were independent**; so they clearly are not.

Comment: As an aside., Yes, $0.24\cdot 0.506\approx 0.121$.  What is given in the table is in fact $0.\color{red}{0}13$, not $0.13$.  If the data in the table is accurate then this would seem to suggest that among those people surveyed in this particular study the females have a lower propensity to pursuing a degree in mathematics than males do (*or whatever the exact interpretation of these events is*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two events $A$ and $B$ are said to be *independent events* **if and only if** $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.

Several real-world examples of independence exist.  For example, the result of a flipped coin being heads versus the result of a die being a $6$ when flipping a coin and throwing a six-sided die simultaneously.  There are however also several real-world examples of events *not* being independent such as the probability that when flipping a single coin it comes up as heads versus it comes up as tails.

Rephrasing a part of that definition, that implies that when $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent, i.e. when $A$ and $B$ are *dependent*, then $Pr(A\cap B)\neq Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  Also it means that if it so happens that $Pr(A\cap B)\neq Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$ then $A$ and $B$ are not independent.

In the given example with the table, the events can be seen to be *dependent* events for exactly the reason that $Pr(A\cap B)\neq Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$

Answer (score 1):

It  means female and math are not independent, otherwise the product would be equal to $0.013$.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All. Basically joint probability and joint probability table are two different things. They are same when the events or variables that we consider are totally independent.